# How to get uiautomatorviewer on windows 10

Tags: android-testing, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I have downloaded android SDK platform tools, but could not find uiautomatorviewer inside it. i am using windows 10 and could not find any documentation regarding uiautomator viewer. Could somebody help

Comment: entering uiautomatorviewer in the command prompt uiautomatorviewer.bat file in the Android installation folder with the following command: Android >> Android-SDK >> Tools >> UIAutomatorViewer.bat        via https://www.browserstack.com/guide/uiautomatorviewer-tutorial#:~:text=This%20can%20be%20done%20by,%3E%3E%20Tools%20%3E%3E%20UIAutomatorViewer.

Comment: Here is the code on github: https://github.com/JingheLee/UIAutomatorViewer